# Value 31 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,30] March

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, jodatime

I get:

> Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException:
>   Cannot parse "1444-05-31 10-10": Value 31 for dayOfMonth must be in
>   the range [1,30]

The code is:

```
    Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm")
            .withChronology(hijri);
    DateTime hijriDt = formatter.parseDateTime("1444-05-31 10-10");
```

I have read somewhere that joda starts counting months from 0 instead of 01. However this is user input and it needs to be parsed via a formatter. I cannot use the regular setters and getters of joda to set the date.

Comment: what is `hijri` variable?

Comment: w/o this additional chronology code works fine

Comment: From what I can piece together, the 5th month in the Hijri calendar only has 29 or 30 days, so that error message seems correct as the date seems not valid.

Comment: The code in the question would be easier to understand if written like this: DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm").withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());

Comment: Yes sorry, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hijri calendar 5 th month takes 30 days. So there is no day like 1444-05-31

Comment: yes, thank you, I was in a rush to finish something I did not notice that!

Comment: More explicitly, it's not about the 5th month; no month has more than 30 days. I think you would see a different error for `1444-04-30` (which only has 29 days).